# Maven says package does not exist but it exist

Tags: maven, junit

I have a maven project (I use Eclipse) with junit test. 
It is a simple project (for robolectric). I have junit tests.

When I run mvn test, I received a message saying that my own package does not exist. Same result, if I run test in Eclipse.

I don't understand. Do you have any suggestion ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>mu.groupid</groupId>
<artifactId>MyAndroidTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MyAndroidTest</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0M10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MyProjectAndroid</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyProjectAndroid</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>13</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**EDIT 2**

I created a new project with same pom.xml file and this time, junit file is found.

**EDIT 3**

Now, I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and it is working in eclipse but the problem persist when I'm running mvn test

Comment: show us how looks like your pom

Comment: Are you using the standard layout directory? http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: pom.xml added and yes, I'm using eclipse to create the pom.xml without archetype.

Comment: I would suggest installing the Maven Eclipse plug-in (Help --> Install new software... -> Search for Maven m2e, install, restart Eclipse and it will natively support Maven projects).

Comment: m2e is alreay installed and I use it with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It is really simple. I was too focused on junit.

I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in project and it is fine now.

The problem seems coming from code generation between eclispe and maven (even if I use m2e)